# Estimate how much large is $\lfloor \log{n!\rfloor}$

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

> Is there a simple method to find or estimate how large  $$\lfloor \lg{n!\rfloor}$$ is ? I'd like to find (or estimate) how much digits $2017!^{2017}$ has, or how much is big that number .

I tried for some little number and general form of $$n!^{n}=\overline{a_k...a_4a_3a_2a_1} \\ k=?$$ so 
I took logarithm of $n!^{n} \mapsto n\log(n!) $.

It is easy when $n$ is little number , but when go for a large number ...what we can do  ? 
My question can be translate as $$n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(i)= ?$$

Comment: I cannot believe you have never met Stirling's inequality in your whole mathematical career, @Khosrotash.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : of course I saw it , but maybe I forgot it or forgot the apllication! thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stirling's approximation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) says that
$$
n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n
$$
Taking logarithms on both sides should be easy enough.

Comment: If we want to determine the precise number of digits, [this two-sided estimate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#cite_ref-Robbins1955_5-0) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

$\lfloor \ln(n!)\rfloor=\sum_{k=2}^n\ln(k) + O(1)$. Since $\int_{k-1}^{k}\ln(t) dt\leq \ln(k)\leq \int_{k}^{k+1}\ln(t) dt$,

$$\int_1^n \ln(t)dt\leq \sum_{k=2}^n\ln(k) \leq \int_2^{n+1}\ln(t)dt$$

Since $\int \ln(x) dx = x\ln(x)-x$ and $\ln(n+1)\sim\ln n$, $$\sum_{k=2}^n\ln(k) = n\ln(n)+o(n\ln n)$$ hence $\lfloor \ln(n!)\rfloor=n\ln(n)+o(n\ln n)$.

However, this is only a partial answer as you need a more precise estimate for your problem.

Comment: :$$\lfloor \ln(n!)\rfloor=n\ln(n)+o(n\ln n)$$ or $$\lfloor \ln(n!)\rfloor=n\ln(n)+o(\ln n)$$ ?

Comment: No, with my computations $\lfloor \ln(n!)\rfloor=n\ln(n)+o(n\ln n)$. With further work, you can prove $\lfloor \ln(n!)\rfloor=n\ln(n)-n+O(\ln n)$. The equality $\lfloor \ln(n!)\rfloor=n\ln(n)+o(\ln n)$ is not true.

Comment: :First thanks for idea .second: It doesn't make a sense when you say $$x+o(x)$$!

Comment: @Khosrotash $u_n\sim v_n \iff u_n=v_n+o(v_n)$.